# Windows 10 IOT Core, Fails to connect using powershell (Objectnotfound measure-object:string)

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot

I followed the steps provided by microsoft to flash windows 10 on a SD card.
inserted this into the raspberry pi 2. It boots just fine showing me the defaultApp.

I am able to connect trough ssh and ftp.
All looks good but I cant connect when I use powershell. I get the following error message:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 10.0.0.24 -Credential Administrator Enter-PSSession : The term 'Measure-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operab le program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1 + Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 10.0.0.24 -Credential Administrator + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Measure-Object:String) [Enter-PSSession], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The device is found by Windows IOT Core Watcher

Comment: Looks like a CmdLet is not available in your session. Did you start the PowerShell console with administrator privileges?

Comment: If you haven't - worth using the Windows 10 IOT Core Dashboard to start the remote powershell session as it takes care of establishing the connection - right click on the device and use the context menu option.